# Is it possible to customize notifications of calendar invites sent with the Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying out the `events.insert` method of the Google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to send calendar invites. With `sendNotifications=True`, the email I receive is a 'standard' GMail calendar invite (see below), in which only the title, description, and reminders are customized (see below).

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to customize this email to include branding, for example? As far I can tell, there isn't any, but perhaps I have overlooked something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to customize the emails I believe. One option to get custom emails is to set sendNotifications=false and instead send your own invitation emails using the Gmail API for example.